# Azure WadLogsTable contains duplicate entries

Tags: azure, azure-diagnostics

I have a web role (2 instances) and a worker role (2 instances) both roles use the following configuration

```
        DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener tmpListener = new DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener();
        System.Diagnostics.Trace.Listeners.Add(tmpListener);
        string wadConnectionString = "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString";
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount =
        CloudStorageAccount.Parse(RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue(wadConnectionString));

        RoleInstanceDiagnosticManager roleInstanceDiagnosticManager =
        storageAccount.CreateRoleInstanceDiagnosticManager(RoleEnvironment.DeploymentId,
        RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.Role.Name, RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.Id);

        DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration config = roleInstanceDiagnosticManager.GetCurrentConfiguration();
        config.Logs.BufferQuotaInMB = 500;
        config.Logs.ScheduledTransferPeriod = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1D);
        config.Logs.ScheduledTransferLogLevelFilter = LogLevel.Information;

        roleInstanceDiagnosticManager.SetCurrentConfiguration(config);
```

When I add some messages I notice that the worker role logs the same entry twice. Do I have to change something?

Comment: Could it be because the diagnostics configuration is same for both instances and each instance will write the same message. Can you check if same instance is writing duplicate messages?

Comment: Each instance writes it's own messages twice

Comment: Did you check if there's already a AzureDiagnosticMonitor in the Trace.Listeners Collection before you add another one?

Comment: Indeed it was.. thanks for the help!

Comment: @Nico - if you re-post your comment as an Answer, Stef (and others) can upvote it and Stef can mark as answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the notice, I will glady repost my hint here as an answer again:

Some project templates in Visual Studio already register an instance of AzureDiagnosticMonitorTraceListener to the Trace.Listeners Collection. You might want to check if there is such a listener already registered before adding a new one:

```
if (Trace.Listeners.OfType<AzureDiagnosticMonitorTraceListener>().Count() == 0)
{
    Trace.Listeners.Add(new AzureDiagnosticMonitorTraceListener());
}
```